# Finding the index of the current element I am scrolling in - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, scroll

Suppose I have some fixed-height auto-scrolled-enabled divs with class name 'class'. I want to find the index of a the current 'class''s  div I am scrolling in, like so :

```
var type = -1;
$(window).scroll(function(type_request){
    type = $('.class').index($(this));console.log(type);
});
```

But I have no output after scrolling.

Comment: Pretty sure you have to bind to `".class"`, not `window`

Comment: `this` in your code refers to window object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your method calls reversed. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    type = $(this).index();
    console.log(type);
});
```

Edit: if you only want to be able to scroll divs with class `.class`, then you need to bind to that specifically:

```
$('.class').scroll(function(){
    type = $(this).index();
    console.log(type);
});
```

Also, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, you should be using `on` instead of `scroll` (which is shorthand for `bind('scroll')`):

```
$('.class').on('scroll', function(){
    type = $(this).index();
    console.log(type);
});
```

Comment: so should I try type = $('this .class').index();  ?

Comment: @undefined jQuery sets the `this` operator to the element triggering the event, in this case whichever element is being scrolled.

Comment: @jbabey That's true, but in your first code, `this` is window object.

Comment: @jbabey Since when? That only happens in delegation

Comment: @Ian since as long as i can remember. "When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered."

Comment: The scroll event doesn't bubble, so you can't capture it by binding the event to `window`, and you can't capture it by delegation. You have to bind to the elements themselves, like you are with `$('.class').on('scroll',` and `$('.class').on('scroll'`

Comment: @jbabey thanks, it didin't work but trying this : $('.class').index($(this));... worked !!!